# C# How can I Kill a startet Process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I developed a Webpage in ASP.NET - the page has a button that starts a DOS-Program on click.

Here is the Code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endTime))
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/");
    p.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath(apiFile);

    try
    {
        p.Start();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "Requested process (" + p.StartInfo.FileName + ") could not be started. Page: Api.aspx.cs, Method: UploadBtn_Click()");
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
}
```

The code works fine and starts the Process.

***Now the Problem:***

I click on the button and the process starts (I see this in the database) and the program works fine, however, I want to stop the process now, but don't know how.

There isn't a DOS-Window where I can click "CTRL + C" or something.

***What can I do to stop the process?***

***And which User is used for starting the Process?***

Comment: Excellent - is this public facing? Can you send me a url? I'd love to try it out :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`Process.Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx):

```
p.Kill();
```

**UPDATE:**
Because of your comment, I provide this as an alternative:
To kill a process without code, use the task manager (open it by using CTRL + SHIFT + ESC or CTRL + ALT + DEL -> Task manager), navigate to the "Processes" tab, choose "Show processes from all users", select your process and click "End process"...

Comment: You'll need to keep a reference to the process so it's accessible when you need to kill it.

Comment: I can't because i start the Process from the Website and not from the visual Studio..

Comment: For explanation: I don't search a Method to stop the Process. I click just Live on the Button. The Process starts... I won't know to kill this Process... I don't need a Code but e solution to stop the Live Process know! :)

Comment: `Process.Kill` has nothing to do with Visual Studio... ?! Do you want to end the process after the sleep? Simple call `p.Kill();` after the sleep...

Comment: @Alexo: You are confusing me. To kill a process without code, use the task manager, navigate to the "Processes" tab, choose "Show processes from all users", select your process and click "End process"...

Comment: thank you! That works with Show Processes from all Users!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store Process object as field under the page class and call .Kill at with another button. But in this case you will be able to host only 1 process and should think of the way to make it safe to run only one.